# Converting a linq query or foreach loop into a form that is awaitable

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to convert my method to Async. I cannot seem to grasp converting a linq query or foreach loop into a form that is awaitable. I read here on SO that EntityFramework + Linq don’t mix very well asynchronously. Perhaps that is why I could not find a previous Question that matches my needs exactly. Would someone care to point me in the right direction?

```
    private static async Task<decimal> GetLastPriceAsync(string customer, string stockNumber)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Get Last Price Called");

        decimal lastCost = 0;
        var lastDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("There was no customer");
            return 0;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("We have a customer");


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stockNumber))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("There was no item");
            return 0;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("We have a Part Number");

        try
        {
            IEnumerable<SA_HistoryHeader> orders =
                DContext.SA_HistoryHeader.Local.Where(c => c.strCustomer == customer);

            if (!orders.Any())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("No order found.");
                return 0;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("We have previous Orders Found");

            foreach (SA_HistoryHeader thisOrder in orders)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Looping through orders.");

                DateTime date = lastDate;

                IEnumerable<SA_HistoryDetail> details = thisOrder.SA_HistoryDetail
                    .Where(i => i.strStock == stockNumber && i.dteLineDate > date && i.bytLineType == 003);

                foreach (
                    SA_HistoryDetail detail in
                        details.Where(detail => detail != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(detail.strDescription)))
                {
                    if (detail.dteLineDate != null)
                    {
                        lastDate = (DateTime) detail.dteLineDate;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Order Date was null");
                    }

                    if (detail.curUnitPrice != null)
                    {
                        lastCost = (decimal) detail.curUnitPrice;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Last Cost was null");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Last Price Calc Error: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
        }

        return lastCost;
    }
```

Comment: I guess the question becomes, what asynchronous operation is being performed here?  While a loop may not complete instantly, that doesn't necessarily mean it's doing anything asynchronously.  Async is generally based around disconnecting the main execution from I/O operations (which return a result later).  Are you looking to offload this to another thread, perhaps?  If so, there's potentially quite a bit more synchronization logic involved than simply awaiting the operation.

Comment: @David, To be clear this is my first actual time trying to write asynchronous code. What I think I am attempting to do is split very large queries into multiple parts running perhaps each on a different thread. Waiting until all tasks are complete to switch back to the main thread. I really don’t know if I can get there from here.

Comment: It's possible that simply using `Parallel.ForEach()` for your loop will do what you need in that case.

Comment: @David, Thanks for your knowledge and input, that helped me a ton.